# module.js:471 throw err: cannot find module

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am using 64bit Windows 7 Ultimate and I want to use my project with Gulp when I run Gulp in the console the below error occurred.

```
module.js:471
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Tiger\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js'
```

So I don't want use gulp from above problem. So what I do now?

Comment: If reinstalling node doesn't solve the missing module error, try to run "**npm install**" - in cmd under your project directory. It should update the _node_modules_ directory with all the required dependencies, as specified in _package.json_ .

Comment: In my case, the problem was that the working directory of the shortcut file that I run node from was the node directory. I removed it so that Windows uses the current directory as the working directory and that fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LOn Linux CentOS:

```
rm -rf /usr/lib/node_module
yum reinstall npm
```

do not update npm

On windows quite the same. Check out where are the libs/modules and delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying ionic folder from

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

to the error location.

Some times even after installing packages from package.json, ionic folder doesn't get created and causes Module.js 471 error.

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Actually this means gulp is corrupted in your computer. Go to task manager and quit the nodeJS service running and then try to reinstall Gulp.